# how to get host name of all LAN systems using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

how to get host name of all LAN systems using c#.net

through "net view" command am getting some systems host names, not able to access all the systems even though they are in the LAN. why so?

Comment: What do you mean by "LAN systems" and what are you trying to do? The list of all domain computers is available through Active Directory. `net view` queries that information, use the same APIs you would eg: ADSI. If you don't see a computer with `net view`it may mean you have no permission to view it, that it isn't part of the domain or that it isn't even a computer, eg a printer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (For no Active directory)

```
public static int GetAllIPAndHostNames()
        {
            string strHostName;

            // Getting Ip address of local machine...
            // First get the host name of local machine.
            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);

            IPHostEntry remoteIP;

            //using host name, get the IP address list..
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

            int i = 0;
            while (i < addr.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
                //HostNames
                remoteIP = Dns.GetHostEntry((addr[i]));
                Console.WriteLine("HostName {0}: {1} ", i, remoteIP.HostName);
                i++;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion, would it be adviseable to use a for loop instead of a while loop? As in for(int i = 0; i < addr.Count; i++).

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static List<String> getAllHostNames()
    {
        List<String> hostNames = new List<String>();
        IPAddress[] ipaddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        String hname;

        foreach (IPAddress ip in ipaddress)
        {
            //if ipv4
            if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                hname = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName.ToLower();
                if (!hostNames.Contains(hname))
                {
                    hostNames.Add(hname);
                }
            }
        }
        return hostNames;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Added the complete code to fetch all the hostnames.

Comment: A more complex solution could be to iterate over all the networkInterfaces of the machine and fetch the hostnames.